# systemverilog assertion - how to ignore first event after reset

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have written following assertion:

```
    assert property(@(posedge ClkRs_ix.clk) 
        disable iff (ClkRs_ix.reset) $stable(Signal_ia)[*20] |-> 
        (Signal_oq==Signal_ia));
```

I wanted to express that *20 clock cycles for which the input signal is stable, at the 21st cycle the output has to have the same value as input.*

This one works, but only if I assure no changes in the state of Signal_ia during the reset. If I assert reset, change the state of Signal_ia, then release the reset, this condition always fails. This usually happens when I start the simulation with Signal_ia = 'X' and during reset it becomes '0'.

Is there any way how to write this better? Resp. is there a way how to ignore first event after reset, as it might be tripping due to conditions happening at reset? If I understood well, iff assures, that this assertion is ignored during reset. Effects I'm trying to describe have some latency, ideally I would need to ignore this condition not only in reset, but as well 20 cycles following the deassertion of the reset state.

thanks
.d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the disable iff (rst) clause is asynchronous. Thus, it does not obey the regular assertion sampling rules.

From the LRM:

> The expression of the disable iff is called the disable condition. The
>   disable iff clause allows preemptive resets to be specified. For an
>   evaluation of the property_spec, there is an evaluation of the
>   underlying property_expr. If the disable condition is true at anytime
>   between the start of the attempt in the Observed region, inclusive,
>   and the end of the evaluation attempt, inclusive, then the overall
>   evaluation of the property results in disabled. A property has
>   disabled evaluation if it was preempted due to a disable iff
>   condition.
>   The values of variables used in the disable condition are those in the
>   current simulation cycle, i.e., not sampled.

In your case, for every cycle prior to the reset, a new thread for your assertion is spawned. Once, the reset comes along, all these instances are disabled and their property evaluation suspended. Any new evaluations will only be started once the reset is de-asserted. Thus, I can't see how this can be the cause of your issue.

However, I can suggest two possible problems that may be causing your problem: 
1. At the beginning of your sim Signal_ia is 'X. After 20 cycles if the reset hasn't been asserted, the antecedent sequence $stable(Signal_ia) will evaluate to true and the assertion will immediate move to evaluating the consequent sequence Signal_oq==Signal_ia (in the same cycle since non-overlapping implication was used). If both these signals are 'X, 1'X == 1'X evaluates to 1'X, thus the assertion will fail. 
2. You mentioned that you want to have the check occur on the 21st cycle. However, this assertion will actually check on the 20th cycle. If there are 20 flops, the output will still be 'X at this point, even if the input has been 0 for 20 cycles.

I suspect option 1. is more likely since 2. would've probably been obvious.

To address both of these, I would recommend that you alter the assertion to trigger on a change of the input to address this.

```
CHECK_OUTPUT:  assert property(@(posedge ClkRs_ix.clk) 
                       disable iff (ClkRs_ix.reset) $changed(Signal_ia) |=>
                            $stable(Signal_ia)[*20] ##0 (Signal_oq==Signal_ia));
```

As pointed out you can also selectively enable the assertion. $asserton and $assetkill (assertoff) can help you do that:

> $asserton[(levels[, list])] is equivalent to $assertcontrol(3, 15,
>   7, levels [,list]) — $assertoff[(levels[, list])] is equivalent to
>   $assertcontrol(4, 15, 7, levels [,list]) — $assertkill[(levels[,
>   list])] is equivalent to $assertcontrol(5, 15, 7, levels [,list])

assertkill will kill any threads that are already running (as opposed to asseroff, which will only prevent future threads). It sounds to me that you would be after assertkill. You can then re-enable your assertion through asserton.

As pointed out, in a formal scenario, naturally this would need to be achieved through a control signal in the assertion and an FSM to generate it.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a *cascaded* implication operator:

```
assert property(@(posedge ClkRs_ix.clk) 
    disable iff (ClkRs_ix.reset) $stable(Signal_ia)[*20] |-> 
    $stable(Signal_ia)[*20] |-> (Signal_oq==Signal_ia));
```

Implication operators are *right-associative* so

```
A |-> B |-> C
```

is equivalent to

```
A |-> (B |-> C)
```

In other words, don't check `B |-> C` until A has occurred.

Another way to achieve this would be to use *satellite code*. Satellite code is code written in the host language, which aids the assertion. So, you could write an FSM that detects the first occurrence of the the first 'event' then enabling the assertion. If you want to be able to check the assertion in a formal tool, make sure you make the satellite code synthesisable.

Comment: In the entire simulation, this assertion will wait for 20 clocks of Signal_ia, then 20 clocks of Signal_ia again and then compare the signals. I believe it will check stability for 40 clocks. As you mentioned, writing some glue logic can be better option.

Comment: @sharvil111 I think differently to you. I think this assertion will wait for 20 clocks of Signal_ia, then _after every further_ 20 clocks of Signal_ia, compare the signals. I guess the questioner needs to implement it and try it out. However, thanks to your comment, I do now see a flaw in my cunning plan: after each 20 clocks of Signal_ia a new thread will start, so by the end of the simulation there will be a zillion concurrent threads running. So, in this case, as you say, writing some glue logic can be better option because of that if nothing else.